# My search bar is delaying updating the results

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was making a search bar component that modifies an array and then a mapping function that displays the resulted array it as the page results, the problem is that the page is delaying to update, in other words when I type a character in the search bar nothing changes but when I add another character the results are being updated with the first character input only and the. 
I was using a hook state to hold the value of the search input and then using a filter function to update the array, finally I used a mapping function to display the modified array data as card components. As I said the problem is the delay that the website takes to update the array and it seams that the problem is with the state hook I uses but I couldn't solve that problem.

I also reuse the filtered array to display search suggetions

Here is app.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import Card from "./components/Card";
import resourcesData from "./resourcesData";
import { type } from "@testing-library/user-event/dist/type";

function App() {
  const [filteredList, setFilteredList] = useState(resourcesData);
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState("");

  const changeInput = (event) => {
    setSearchTerm(event);

  };
  function handleSearchTerm(event) {
    setSearchTerm(event.target.value);

    var updatedList = [...resourcesData];
    updatedList = updatedList.filter((val) => {
      if (searchTerm === "") return val;
      else if (
        val.title.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLocaleLowerCase())
      ) {
        return val;
      } else if (
        val.thematicArea
          .toLocaleLowerCase()
          .includes(searchTerm.toLocaleLowerCase())
      ) {
        return val;
      } 
    
    });

    setFilteredList(updatedList);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        type="text"
        value={searchTerm}
        onChange={handleSearchTerm}
        className="input"
      ></input>
      <div className="dropdown">
        {filteredList.slice(0, 10).map((item) => (
          <div
            onClick={() => changeInput(item.title)}
            className="dropdown-row"
            key={item.title}
          >
            {item.title}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>

      <div className="cards">
        {filteredList.map((value, index) => (
          <Card
            resourceURL={value.link}
            thumbnailURL=""
            title={value.title}
            subtitle=""
            date={value.date}
            description=""
            cost=""
            cardkeywords={
              value.cost === "free"
                ? [
                    value.level,
                    value.language,
                    value.type,
                    value.thematicArea,
                    value.cost,
                  ]
                : [
                    value.level,
                    value.language,
                    value.type,
                    ...value.thematicArea.split(","),
                  ]
            }
            key={index}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: const changeInput = (event) => {
    setSearchTerm(event);

  }; //changeinput is what ? you are changing the input value and set that value to searchterm ?

Comment: you use `event.target.value` for filtering as well .... as state updates are async - they are available ready for next render ..

Comment: @RahulMohanty
The `changeInput` is called when a search suggestion is clicked so that the search term update to what was clicked ```  <div
            onClick={() => changeInput(item.title)}
            className="dropdown-row"
            key={item.title}
          >
            {item.title}
          </div>
```

Comment: @RahulMohanty event.target.value worked thanks alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the function `handleSearchTerm` you use `setSearchTerm(event.target.value);` and after you are using `searchTerm` which updates asynchronously.
Use in this function `event.target.value`.

```
function handleSearchTerm(event) {
const newValue = event.target.value;
setSearchTerm(newValue);

var updatedList = [...resourcesData];
updatedList = updatedList.filter((val) => {
  if (newValue === "") return val;
  else if (
    val.title.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(newValue.toLocaleLowerCase())
  ) {
    return val;
  } else if (
    val.thematicArea
      .toLocaleLowerCase()
      .includes(newValue.toLocaleLowerCase())
  ) {
    return val;
  } 

});

setFilteredList(updatedList);
```

}

Comment: This worked but the problem is that I need to use state hook as I need to use the `    setSearchTerm()` funtion in the `changeInput()` function as you can see in my code, any suggestions?

Comment: I think I don't understand your requirement. 
You use it at the beginning of the handleSearchTerm function: 

`const newValue = event.target.value;
setSearchTerm(newValue);`

Can you please describe what exactly doesn't work for you?

Comment: I have function in my code that displays search suggestions and it changes the search input once a search suggestion is clicked, the problem is that the array isn't updated as the search term is asynchronous , I'm searching for a method for force rendering my component as I think it might help do you have any suggestions?